# OSRM: Modifying bicycle.lua

Tags: docker, lua, openstreetmap

I have set up OSRM (Open Source Routing Machine) on a Windows 11 machine with WSL (Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS) and Docker installed.

```
docker pull osrm/osrm-backend
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from osrm/osrm-backend
aed007321795: Pull complete
595e916ac67a: Pull complete
69f309e04f11: Pull complete
e73ad3e5bcf3: Pull complete
4c20f809069e: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:af5d4a83fb90086a43b1ae2ca22872e6768766ad5fcbb07a29ff90ec644ee409
Status: Downloaded newer image for osrm/osrm-backend:latest
docker.io/osrm/osrm-backend:latest
```

```
docker run -t -v /mnt/c/docker:/data osrm/osrm-backend osrm-extract -p /opt/bicycle.lua /data/south_west_highways.osm.pbf
docker run -t -v /mnt/c/docker:/data osrm/osrm-backend osrm-partition /data/south_west_highways.osrm
docker run -t -v /mnt/c/docker:/data osrm/osrm-backend osrm-customize /data/south_west_highways.osrm
docker run --name osrm -t -i -p 5000:5000 -v /mnt/c/docker:/data osrm/osrm-backend osrm-routed --algorithm mld /data/south_west_highways.osrm
```

It runs correctly and I'm able match bike GPX tracks to OSM ways.

I would now like to modify bicycle.lua to allow routes on 'main' roads - but I can't find /opt/bicycle.lua ?

https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend/blob/master/profiles/bicycle.lua

Where should this file be located on my system?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer!  In the command

```
docker run -t -v /mnt/c/docker:/data osrm/osrm-backend osrm-extract -p /opt/bicycle.lua /data/south_west_highways.osm.pbf
```

just point to the new file that you want to refer to e.g.

```
docker run -t -v /mnt/c/docker:/data osrm/osrm-backend osrm-extract -p /my_location/my_lua_file.lua /data/south_west_highways.osm.pbf
```